# On hover, how to override an existing animation style?

Tags: html, css

See the snippet below. Notice when you hover over an item, the item's background color changes but the `transform: translateY(-5px)` is being ignored. The hover's transform style only works if the .list-item animation is not set.

How can I get the `translateY(-5px)` on hover to work in the code?

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 24px 0;
}

.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #EFEFEF;

  animation-name: popin;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: .6s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.list-item:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

@keyframes popin {
  0%{
    transform:scale(0);
  }
  50%{
    transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100%{
    transform:scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I also need to have a transition when the translation is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last state from the animation since it's the default one and you will be able to override the transform. Basically the animation will consider the state of the element as the `100%` and when you change it on hover it will also change in the animation.

> If a 100% or to keyframe is not specified, then the user agent constructs a 100% keyframe using the computed values of the properties being animated.<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#keyframes)</sup>

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 24px 0;
}

.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #EFEFEF;

  animation-name: popin;
  animation-fill-mode:both;
  animation-duration: .6s;
  /*animation-iteration-count: 1; also not needed */
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.list-item:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

@keyframes popin {
  0%{
    transform:scale(0);
  }
  50%{
    transform:scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

if you want the transition you can adjust the code slightly to be able to have two elements where it would be easy to apply transform independently:

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 24px 0;
}

.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 14px;

  animation-name: popin;
  animation-fill-mode:both;
  animation-duration: .6s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.list-item:before {
  content:attr(data-text);
  display:block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  transition:1s all;
}

.list-item:hover:before  {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

@keyframes popin {
  0%{
    transform:scale(0);
  }
  50%{
    transform:scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item" data-text="item"></div>
  <div class="list-item" data-text="item"></div>
  <div class="list-item" data-text="item"></div>
  <div class="list-item" data-text="item"></div>
  <div class="list-item" data-text="item"></div>
  <div class="list-item" data-text="item"></div>
</div>
```

You can also consider an extra wrapper like below:

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 24px 0;
}

.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 14px;

  animation-name: popin;
  animation-fill-mode:both;
  animation-duration: .6s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.list-item > div {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  transition:1s all;
}

.list-item:hover > div  {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

@keyframes popin {
  0%{
    transform:scale(0);
  }
  50%{
    transform:scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item"><div>item</div></div>
  <div class="list-item"><div>item</div></div>
  <div class="list-item"><div>item</div></div>
  <div class="list-item"><div>item</div></div>
  <div class="list-item"><div>item</div></div>
  <div class="list-item"><div>item</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx but that causes the items to flash/flicker on load -- what's happening now, is you see the items, then the items animate...

Comment: When you first run the code snippet, you see the flashing

Comment: @AnApprentice hmm ... you want to have a transition for the translate? because I have another solution without transition

Comment: Thanks for that.. This is so close! Problem is (new problem), now the transition on the hover is now working. I updated the question with the latest snippet ... Notice how on hover, this is not being applied `transition:
    box-shadow .1s ease,
    transform 0.1s ease-in-out;` -- any ideas?

Comment: @AnApprentice ok so you want the transition, I will think about ... please don't update the question to remove the old problem as my answer is now irrelevant :) simply edit to add that you want to also have the transition

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work -- in actuality, the items have a series of divs etc. I just used the "text" item to keep the snippet simple.

Comment: @AnApprentice in this case you can simply consider an extra wrapper like `<div class="item"><div>...</div></div>` where you add the scale to the item and the transform to the inner div and then all your content is inside

Comment: oh that's a very smart idea. want to update the snippet so I can accept?

Answer (score 0):

I was actually facing a similar problem the other day. I can't tell you why it behaves like this but I can tell you how I solved it. I created another animation and activated it on `hover`. I used `animation-fill-mode: forwards` so the animation would only go back to its initial state after you hover somewhere else. 
Give it a try and let me know what you think.

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 24px 0;
}

.list-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #EFEFEF;

  animation-name: popin;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: .6s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
 
.list-item:hover {
  animation: pull-up 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@keyframes popin {
  0%{
    transform:scale(0);
  }
  50%{
    transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100%{
    transform:scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes pull-up {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
  <div class="list-item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this causes all kinds of jumping and flashing.  Would you mind making this a runnable snippet?

Comment: very helpful.. in this snippet. you'll notice when hover and then remove the mouse, the items flash. the flash is not desired.

Comment: The flashing is caused by the `popin` animation. `popin` is triggered on mouse leave.